# Recompose async prop update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recompose

How to rerender component with recompose, when prop is changed from outside the view component?

```
const Message = ({msg}) => <div>The prop has a value of <b>{msg}</b>.</div>

const App = Recompose.withProps(() => {
  let msg = 'One'

  // this async update doesn't work because nothing triggers a rerender
  setTimeout(() => {msg = 'Two'}, 500)

  return {msg}
})(Message)


ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

When this component is rendered, it shows value as **One** but doesn't change to **Two** after 500ms even though it changes the prop.

The `setTimeout` here simplifies the case when in the actual usecase I subscribe to websocket server and when a message is pushed, the Message component gets updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I did not work with recompose actively yet.

But what I know is that your component should be stateful. I found [`withState` in recompose docs](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose#lift-state-into-functional-wrappers)

```
const enhance = withState('counter', 'setCounter', 0)
const Counter = enhance(({ counter, setCounter }) =>
  <div>
    Count: {counter}
    <button onClick={() => setCounter(n => n + 1)}>Increment</button>
    <button onClick={() => setCounter(n => n - 1)}>Decrement</button>
  </div>
)
```

So what I think is, you need to define the state `msg` using `withState` and then you can pass the `setMsg` into your component. when calling this `setMsg` within your `setTimeout` an update should be performed.

```
const withMsg = withState('msg', 'setMessage', '');
```